# Java/RegEx - How to find the first non-word number in a string?

Tags: java, android, regex

I want a regular expression that matches based on this rule: searching for the first number in a string and checking if it's alone in its neighborhood (the character before and after the number is SPACE, or the character before is SPACE and it's the ending part of the string).

A few examples below:

- `ABC AB34.1 ABC 39.25 AB` : `39.25`
- `ABC AB34.1 ABC 39.25` : `39.25`
- `ABC 34.1AB ABC 39.25` : `39.25`

I know that `/^[^\d]*(\d+)/` can match the first number in the string, but I don't know how to check if it contains SPACES before and after itself, or SPACE before and maybe `\n` after.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?`, see [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/IujsPI/2). In Java, you will need `if (matcher.find()) {` and get `matcher.group()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but what about the first one? This example that you wrote will match a number if its at the beginning of the string, be it attached to a letter or not. Can we do something to ignore it completely if it's the first? I know I can check the index in java, but I wanna know if it's possible in RegEx. @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: `39.25` is not at the start of `ABC AB34.1 ABC 39.25 AB : 39.25`. Didn't you ask to extract the first standalone float value from a string? Or do you want ``^(?:.*?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)){2}`` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/IujsPI/3))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. The first one works great, however I had one question. I want something exactly like the first one (finding the first standalone float value) BUT ignoring it if it's at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
(?!^)\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
(?!\A)\b(?<!\d\.)\d+(?:\.\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IujsPI/4). In Java, after initializing the `Matcher` object, execute it inside an `if` block (not `while`) to get the first match.

*Pattern details*:

- `(?!^)` - not at the start of string (`\A` is an unambiguous string start anchor)
- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\d\.)` - a negative lookbehind that matches a location not immediately preceded with a digit and `.`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - the consuming pattern part that matches one or more digits and then an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IujsPI/4).

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/vk0IGo):

```java
String s = "34.1 ABC AB34.1 ABC 39.25 AB : 19.15";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?!^)\\b(?<!\\d\\.)\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group()); 
} else {
    System.out.println("No match found in '" + s + "'!"); 
}
// => 39.25
```

Answer (score 0):

[^\d]+[\s]+([\d]+[.]+[\d]+)[\s]+

In English, basically this string checks if

- one or zero non-digits
- one or zero spaces
- digits (with one possible decimal point)
- one or zero spaces.

https://regex101.com/r/0DQvDd/1

Comment: Thanks, but this also matches the letters. For example, in case of "abc efg 55.3 1h23", efg 55.3 is matched. Or am I wrong?

Comment: This matches only 55.3.